# Ziox Astra Star bootloop and vertical lines

Tags: boot-loop, bootloader

My old Ziox Astra Star phone started going to boot loop, restarting automatically without launching the OS. So, someone suggested that the ROM  could have been corrupted.

I remember trying to put it in recovery mode and it worked once, but not anymore. No matter what combination of buttons I use, the phone doesn't go to recovery mode.

The combination (power + volume up) sometimes shows the screen with vertical lines. The display is ok as I see the startup logo of Ziox, but nothing after that.

Is eMMC gone bad? Is there anything I can try (even solder or desolder eMMC?)

Comment: if eMMC wear-out is your suspect you are probably right, because average lifetime is 2-3 years. maybe the phone is in recovery mode but you can not see it. try fastboot instead and check bootloader lock state

Comment: @alecxs +1 for suggestion. If eMMC is worn out, would we see vertical lines? I will look at fastboot.